# How to parse a JSON file in javascript without having any knowledge about the contents of the file?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, key

I would like to know how to parse any JSON file irrespective of the contents.
For example, I have to parse the following JSON. How would I parse it and call values without using words/keys from the JSON file?

```
var a = [{
    "Master Row": "P558:15",
    "Prefix*": "5C34",
    "Base*": "1508",
    "Suffix*": "CA",
    "Weight Unit of Measure": "lb"
}, {
    "Master Row": "P558:16",
    "Prefix*": "5C34",
    "Base*": "1508",
    "Suffix*": "CA",
    "Weight Unit of Measure": "lb"
}]
```

Comment: You would have to iterate it, otherwise you have no way of knowing if a key or index exists

Comment: or perhaps turning it into an object using `eval()`?

Comment: `Object.keys()` might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a loop to go through each element in a, and a loop to go through each key in the objects.
(Also you are missing a comma between prefix and base in the first object)

```js
var a= [ { "Master Row":"P558:15", "Prefix*":"5C34","Base*":"1508", "Suffix*":"CA", "Weight Unit of Measure":"lb" }, { "Master Row":"P558:16", "Prefix*":"5C34", "Base*":"1508", "Suffix*":"CA", "Weight Unit of Measure":"lb" } ];

for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  var temp=a[i];
  for(key in temp){
    console.log(key+' '+temp[key]);
  }
}
```